# Sampling texture to small area of a large mesh

Tags: opengl, graphics, vulkan

I'm trying to implement water reflections in a large body of water. The water fills the entire horizontal distance of camera Frustum. My player is over the water. But I want that only the area close to the camera shows reflection. By scaling up the plane (which is the mesh used for water displacement) it also scales the reflection texture.

I would like to apply the reflection texture only to the area close to the camera. Any idea?

Comment: "*But I want that only the area close to the camera shows reflection.*" That's kind of the opposite of how reflection works over actual water.

Comment: As @NicolBolas said, that's not the way water reflections work. Usually the water surface would appear more reflective in the distace due to the Fresnel effect. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Principle-of-the-Fresnel-effect-the-amount-of-reflection-on-a-reflective-surface-depends_fig3_319178578

Comment: Checkout this YouTube series of videos by ThinMatrix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HusvGeEDU_U

Comment: Woud give me a direction on how do I make these displacement water technique to large bodies of water. Since scaling distorts the textures.